# What could be one word for time off for family/personal work?

Tags: terminology, slang, single-word-requests

What could be a word/one word and slang for a time-off period, that someone took for his personal/family work?

i.e. I took time-off from office to do some personal work, household chores.

The word should convey the meaning that I took the off from office, but I could not relax during the time off, rather I was very busy.

Something like "work + vacation = worcation", I know it's not a word :D

Comment: In the US, the initialism PTO (personal time off) is used in everyday speech. Many companies use the term for paid leave that you accrue. The idea is to simplify vacation and sick leave and not distinguish between them.

Comment: @PhilSweet Does that suggest that employees have to take vacation leave if they are sick? I think that would be illegal in the UK.

Answer (score -1):

Actually ***[workation](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/workation)*** appears to be a recent usage, though not common yet:

> A workation (sometimes spelled 'workcation') is a working vacation (in the UK we might call it a ['workoliday](https://www.lexico.com/definition/working_holiday)', or a 'woliday')

> A vacation that combines business and leisure.

Usage examples:

> 2013, Vanessa Van Edwards, How I Make My Living on ‘Workations’, The Huffington Post- *As long as you do it right, a workation could very well improve your performance.*

> 2016, Brian David Crane, From Vacation to Workation: An Insider’s Guide for Digital Nomads, Tech.co -
> *I had planned a vacation. What I really needed and wanted was a “workation” –  a trip designed not just for exploring international destinations, but also for productivity and personal and professional growth.*

Comment: A 'workation' **combines business** and leisure. Not household chores and leisure.